# Display in ExtJS

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, extjs4

I am having a problem in displaying my ExtJS grid. Early this day it was working fine. Now that I run it again, it is not the same anymore. The UI was damaged. I dont know what to do. I tried restarting the Eclipse, the browser even my PC. I also tried making another JSP but still the UI is damaged.

[image: This is the sc]

[This is the link of the screenshot..](http://dc427.4shared.com/img/hHF8-pUk/s7/0.45000610714299316/error.PNG?async)

Comment: Did u made any update? Edit your question with the program and error stacktrace,

Comment: i did. I just updated the store and my servlet. But when I encountered this problem, I undo all the things I did but unfortunately, it came to worst. :(

Comment: We aren't mind readers here. Show us your broken piece of code. Also, pay some attention to the style of the broken component, as your console error *clearly* stated that.

Comment: Im sorry.. Thanks for helping.. ^____^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your statement, the code has been working and you had just added store and/or servlet configuration. Then you may be experiencing a folder name or a path error. Check your naming in folder\component varaible\store names embedded in controller, etc...

Another thing worth noting is that you told that you reverted your code and tried. So, if that is the case, did you clear cache of the browser, as it may solve your problem.

Comment: @hariharan.. I just restored my code from last week's local history.. Thanks for always helping..